# require once doesn't work in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, yii

I tried to use `phpmvc` in the `system` folder. I have some classes that in start of project. I used them but in my `index.php` it doesn't recognize them

```
<?php
define('test', true);

require_once('/system/loader.php');

$uri = getRequestUri();
>
```

loader is  in folder system:

```
<?
echo '11111';////for test that is call
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');

global $config;
require_once('/config.php');
require_once('/system/core.php');
require_once('/system/common.php');
require_once('/system/db.php');
require_once('/system/view.php');
require_once('/locale/' . $config['lang'] . '.php');
?>
```

But it doesn't show `111` or in `common.php`. I have function `getRequestUri()` but when I call it directly, `common.php`, my function works

htaccess is:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /framework/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Why my `require_once('/system/loader.php');` doesn't work and shows that it can't find `getRequestUri` ?

Comment: can you try `echo '1111;'` . I see in your code concatenation problem is there. Please check and let us know

Comment: Are you aware of when and when not to use a leading slash on a file path?

Comment: i write ' wrong but in my code is true

Comment: Also try using [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function to check if file exist, and please read [Absolute path vs relative path in Linux/Unix](http://www.linuxnix.com/abslute-path-vs-relative-path-in-linuxunix/)

Comment: mr Hanky Panky you mean what? can you explain more

Comment: you can get a better idea about the error by setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors","ON");` after `define('test', true);`

Comment: "require oncee" will not work ever, "require_once" will

Comment: i use it but just show last error : Call to undefined function getRequestUri() in C:\wamp\www\framework\index.php on line 6

Comment: Change path to correct ones '/system/core.php' is not correct